# Is it possible with C++ to orchestrate the offset of a base class relative to its derived class?

Tags: c++, g++, multiple-inheritance

Consider the following "black box",

```
template<std::size_t offset, typename T>
class BlackBox;
```

Which must have the following feature:

```
class SomeClass; // This class has a virtual destructor
                 // and a default constructor.

constexpr std::size_t offset = alignof(SomeClass);
auto bb = new BlackBox<offset, SomeClass>;
SomeClass* ptr = bb;
assert((char*)ptr - (char*)bb == offset); // OK(!)
delete ptr;  // OK - destructs and deletes bb correctly.
```

Here `offset` is always a non-negative multiple of `alignof(SomeClass)`, but for the sake of this question you may assume it is exactly one times `alignof(SomeClass)`.

Furthermore you may assume that `alignof(SomeClass) <= alignof(std::max_align_t)`.

If it is not possible within (any) C++ standard, then you may assume that the compiler used is a recent version of g++.

I am well aware that this falls under "dirty programming"; nevertheless I kinda "need it". The question is if it is possible (and how) with whatever hacks possible.

I tried the following, **but this does not work**:

```
template<std::size_t offset, typename T>
struct Offset {
  typename std::aligned_storage<offset, alignof(T)>::type m_offset;
};

template<std::size_t offset, typename T>
class BlackBox : Offset<offset, T>, public T {
  static_assert(offset % alignof(T) == 0, "");
  using T::T;
};
```

The problem here is that there is no guarantee on how base classes in the case of multiple inheritance are ordered in memory, and as soon as T has a virtual table, it is placed first in memory (by g++) - immediately reducing the offset calculated in the assert to 0.

Comment: @user10605163 What do you mean? It compiles fine for me. It's just that the assert fails. If you mean the line `SomeClass* ptr = bb;` before the assert, well - that is the demand. If you write BlackBox correctly that works fine (and really isn't the problem). Have a look at the the code block below "but this doesn't work". That "works" in the sense that it compiles without errors. Only the assert fails, and even then only with some compilers (depending on the compiler implementation it might actually work).

Comment: So, to clarify: the question is how to write BlackBox such that the given code *does* compile and runs fine. In order for the line ` SomeClass* ptr = bb;` to work, `SomeClass` could for example be a base class of `BlackBox<offset, SomeClass>`. Or, you could overload `operator SomeClass*()`...

Comment: OK, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: The Itanium ABI (used by g++ and clang++) will always put a vptr at the beginning of every polymorphic object layout, so this is not possible if `alignof(SomeClass) < sizeof(void*)`.

Comment: I'm curious why you think you need it as opposed to a more definable way to guarantee byte ordering.

Comment: @aschepler But as stated, `SomeClass` has a virtual destructor, so its alignment will be at least `sizeof(void*)` and never less. You may assume that it is exactly that, and not larger either.

Comment: @DaveNewton I want a class (say `C`) that 'has a' `Socket`, but where the user may derive from `Socket`. So `C` only needs to know about the interface of `Socket`, but the member needs to have the virtual table of whatever type the user derived from `Socket`. I do not want `C` to be a template however (aka, `template<typename SocketDerived> class C { ... SocketDerived m_socket; };`).  The only other normal approach would be to use a pointer `Socket* m_socket` as member, but I'm trying to avoid the extra indirection. Instead of `SocketDerived` I am using a place holder `DerivedFrom<Socket>`.

Comment: @DaveNewton The problem now is that this leads to an alignment (relative to the beginning of C) of `alignof(DerivedFrom<Socket>)` which I can enforce to `std::max_align_t`, but that would waste a lot of space :p. So, instead I'm aligning `DerivedFrom<Socket>` as `alignof(Socket)`. In the case that the user class that is derived from `Socket` is more strict (ie, `alignof(Socket) == 8`, and `alignof(SocketDerived) == 16`) it might be necessary to shift `C` 8 bytes relative to an address aligned at 16 in order to get `DerivedFrom` be aligned at 16 again. That is what I need this for.

Comment: Here is a test case for that: https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-utils-testsuite/blob/master/src/derived_from_test.cxx  which uses https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-utils/blob/8362b58f2debd13813f94c5196a9caf1fe8a8158/HasDerivedFrom.h#L169

Comment: That's *what* you need, I'm asking *why*..